# Augmented reality iPhone with ARToolKit, Pb with UIImagePickerController and UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, augmented-reality

I am currently working on an app with augmented reality. I chose to use the ARToolKit library (available on github).
I have a little problem to integrate my view in my project.
The problem is that I can not see my navigationbar when UIImagePickerController is launched

AugmentedRealityController.m

```
- (Void) displayAr
[RootViewController presentModalViewController: [self cameraController] animated: NO];
[DisplayView setFrames: [[[self cameraController] view] bounds]];
```

)

I guess the problem come from here. I can not view the UIImagePickerController that if I go through presentModalViewController.
By making a pushviewcontroller from my navigation controller it does not work either (after read documentation).
After some research on documentation should be implemented by the delegate access UIImagePickerController and UINavigationController. Even with that it does not work either (sniff).

I picked this version here: http://github.com/nielswh/iPhone-AR-Toolkit/commit/681165d383ab590d03a0daaf761bc25b59d1acd6

I adapted a few things so that his running iOS 4.1 (actually this version is 3.1.3).

I do not know if there have been changes regarding the use of UIImagePickerController since.

If anyone has an idea, help or something. After half a day searching the internet I try many things in vain